# Unable to get data from database using AJAX & PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

**Update:** The first part of this question has been solved and has been updated below with the working code.
~

I’m working on a Javascript application and I’m having difficultly getting an AJAX call to work.

I’m able to successfully insert data into my database using AJAX POST & PHP but I can’t seem to pull data from the database.

I have a Javascript application which uses an image, currently it gets this image from a location in the root folder like this:

```
img.src = 'picture1.jpg';
```

Instead of doing this, I want to select a random image from a table in the database every time the Javascript application loads.

I’ve created a table with a single column, and populated this with the addresses/locations of images contained in a folder in my root directory.

For example:

```
/images/00001.jpg
/images/00002.jpg
/images/00003.jpg
```

This is the PHP file (located at /scripts/imagerandomizer.php) I’m using to call a random image address:

```
<?php 

session_start();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = "mydatabase";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sqlrandomize = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT images FROM `images` ORDER BY RAND( ) LIMIT 0 , 1");

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($sqlrandomize);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($row);

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

And the AJAX which initiates the PHP & listens for the echo:

```
function getRandomImage() {

$.ajax({
     url: 'scripts/imagerandomizer.php',
    data: "",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
         alert(response);
    }});
};
```

I’m trying to use *alert(data);* to have the randomly chosen image location/address appear in an alert box (just to see if it’s working). But it’s not working for me, I’m pretty sure I've made a mistake somewhere, and I’m not sure if `json` is the right data type to use here?

I would like to have the returned address replace the current `img.src = 'image.jpg';` , so that when the Javascript application starts, it will receive a random image from the `img.src =` section of code.

Thanks for any help on this!

**UPDATE:**

The Javascript can now correctly display a random address (using either “alert” or “console.log”) every time it’s loaded. The last part of my question concerns how to have a .js file read this string, and use it as the location of an image that it then fetches.

This is how my game is set up:
I have a file named “game.js”, it contains the code needed for the game to operate, right now, part of that code is this: `img.src = 'images/image00001.jpg';`  Right now that image is permanently defined and doesn’t change. I’m trying to replace this static definition with the randomized one. Basically I’m trying to get the randomized address to appear after `img.src =` whenever game.js loads.

I also need to make sure that this event happens before the rest of the game.js code initiates, as I need the randomly chosen image file to be in place before the rest of the game loads. 
I’ve tried defining img.src by including `img.src=(response)` in the AJAX call at the top of the game.js file but it’s failing to load any image into the game. I’m thinking that maybe this is the wrong way to do this?

**2nd UPDATE**

Hi @PHPGlue
I’ve been trying to get this to work for days now but I’m still missing something.

This is my function to grab the randomized image, and I’ve tried to place the code to run the game in the success function `if (img.src) {//code to run the game here}`:

```
Function getRandomImage() {
    $.ajax({
     url: 'scripts/imagerandomizer.php',
    data: "",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){

$('#imageId').attr('src', data.image);
img.src = $('#imageId');

if (img.src) {
 //code to run the game here
}
        }});
};
```

I’m definitely missing something here, I think I’m not understanding what you mean correctly. I’d really appreciate any advice on this and thank you again for taking the time to look at my question!

**3rd Update**

Hi, my current code is:

```
function getRandomImg(gameFunc){
  $.post('scripts/imagerandomizer.php', {randImg:1}, function(data){
    var im = $('#imageId');
    im.attr('src', data.image);
    im.load(function(){
      gameFunc(img.src=im);
    }
  }, 'json');
}
getRandomImg(function(){
  javascriptgame();
});

function javascriptgame(){
//in this area I’ve placed all the code to make the game work
}
```

When you said `/* pass args to gameFunc here */` I entered `img.src=im`. (I’m not sure I understand you correctly but I think I’m supposed to define the `img.src=` for the game to call in this line?

When you said `// game code here - could also pass function name instead of Anonymous function`, I created a new function called `javascriptgame`, inside which I placed the game’s code, and then called this function at this line. I’m not sure if that’s what you meant for me to do?

Unfortunately right now there’s still no image loading into the game, I want to thank you again for taking the time to help me with this and if you could offer any more advice that would be awesome! Thanks so much.

Comment: just add this line in your php before json_encode : header('Content-Type: application/json');

Comment: Check the error logs for php and let us know if it has anything in there.

Comment: Hi @imranqasim & @JClaspill I added ``header('Content-Type: application/json');`` to my code And I checked Apache's error folder but I can't see any recorded errors. It's still not working though.

Comment: is there a `images` column in your `images` table? Should that not be `select *` or `select src` or something? What if you inspect your ajax response, or if you surf directly to that ajax url? Does it contain in data, or errors perhaps?

Comment: Hi @Pevara yes that's correct the table is named "images" and the column inside the table is named "images", when I run the query ``"SELECT images FROM `images` ORDER BY RAND( ) LIMIT 0 , 1"`` in the SQL console it correctly returns a random image address, so that part seems to be working fine. I'm not sure what you mean by surfing directly to the ajax url, the url contained in the ajax code is the location from the root folder to the PHP script, I also tried moving the script directly into the root folder and changing the url accordingly but this hasn't solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your mysqli_query()
It should be like 
mysqli_query(connection,query,resultmode)
Where connection and query are required and resultmode is optional.

Example: 
mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT images FROM `images` ORDER BY RAND( ) LIMIT 0 , 1");

For more details please check out 
[mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: Hi @shahbaz-masud thanks for your advice, I added the "$conn," to my PHP code and it now seems to be partly working, the "alert(data)" is now returning "[object Object]", I'm trying to have it return something like "/images/00001.jpg", do you know why it isn't rendering this data correctly?

Comment: Because the server is giving you some object, not a string value, and `alert` sucks at printing objects. I suggest you stop using `alert` and start using `console.log` to see what is really going on - much more useful for debugging. I believe you are giving back the resultset object; you probably want to extract a string from that in PHP already before you send it back.

Comment: I knew it but just wanted you to figure it out. The mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For fetching data out of the object one can use mysqli_fetch_row or mysqli_fetch_assoc etc.
Example: $row = mysqli_fetch_row($sqlrandomize))  Then you just gotta change this 
echo json_encode($row);

Comment: Thanks @shahbazmasud and Amadan very much for your responses, I really appreciate all your advice. It’s working now! :) and I’ve edited my question to include the working code. I’ve also written an update at the bottom about the second part of my question that I’m still having some trouble with, if you’d like to take a look that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

First you should make a separate secure PHP connection page

```
// connection.php
<?php
function db(){
  return new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');
}
?>
```

You're problem is that you don't actually get any results by just making a query. You still have to get the query results and use them in your code:

```
<?php
include 'connection.php'; $db = db(); $r = array();
if(isset($_POST['randImg'])){
  if(+$_POST['randImg'] === 1){
    if($iq = $db->query('SELECT images image FROM images ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1')){
      if($iq->num_rows > 0){
        $fi = $iq->fetch_object(); $r['image'] = $fi->image;
      }
      else{
        // no results were found
      }
      $iq->free();
    }
    else{
      // connection failure
    }
  }
  else{
    // randImg hack
  }
}
echo json_encode($r);
$db->close();
?>
```

Get that in JavaScript as `data.image` inside your `success` function.

```
function getRandomImg(gameFunc){
  $.post('scripts/imagerandomizer.php', {randImg:1}, function(data){
    var im = $('#imageId');
    im.attr('src', data.image);
    im.load(function(){
      gameFunc(/* pass args to gameFunc here */);
    }
  }, 'json');
}
getRandomImg(function(){
  // game code here - could also pass function name instead of Anonymous function
});
```

Comment: Hi @PHPglue thanks for your advice, I've updated my question with working code now and I'll be making the connection & console.log changes you suggested soon. I've written some more about the second part of my question in the update if you'd like to have a look, thanks again for your help!

Comment: An Element has to exist before you have access to it. Of course, you need the correct `data.image` path: `$('#imageId').attr('src', data.image);`. `games.js` needs to be in the folder where the `images` folder is located. You will need to run your game code inside the success function to load the image first.

Comment: Hi @PHPglue I've been trying to get this to work for a week now but I'm still not able to work it out, I've added a 2nd update to my question and was wondering if you could take a look at my code and advise me on where I'm going wrong? Thanks so much again!

Comment: Hi @PHPglue firstly, thanks so much for your help on this! I’m trying to implement your updated code and was wondering if you could take a look to see where I’m going wrong. I’m using the php code exactly as you gave me, but I think I’m making a mistake with the Javascript code, I've written a 3rd update to my question if you could take a look :)